# How to convert a string return from a JQuery slider UI into a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two sliding bars and I want to get the value the user sets them to and do some maths on it. var days and var total are my attempts to do this. I was taking it that the UI slider stores its values as stings and not integers. But both my attempts below, then use either just return a NaN value? So what am I doing wrong?

```
var days = parseInt($(this).attr('#day_output'), 10);
var total = parseInt($('#amount_outputTotal'));
var fees = 5;
var valueout;

valueout = 60 * days + fees;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Output').html(valueout);
});
```

Many Thanks Glenn.

Comment: jQuery UI has [methods](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#methods). Why can't you use method ["value"](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#method-value)?

Answer (score 0):

Why would a slider, which is a representation of numbers, store the value as strings? You can get the value (or values, if two handles) with the following code

```
var val_single = $('#your_slider').slider('value');

var val_array = $('#your_slider').slider('values');
```

Please rtfm http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: I just assumed (wrong thing to do, I know) that it was in a string, but thanks for the very fast reply! I play around with that!

Answer (score 0):

One of our projects using jqueryUI ahs following code:

```
fixed = $().fixFloat(ui.value);
```

I understand that this might don't suit your needs.

Try to change from parseInt to parseFloat and also output via console:

```
$(this).attr('#day_output')
```

Why here is nothing like .attr or .val or something?

```
$('#amount_outputTotal')
```